# How to change EJB JNDI bindings in WebSphere Liberty

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, jndi, websphere-liberty

I have an `ear` application which is deployed to WebSphere Liberty 8.5. The application includes an EJB module in which I declared a few EJBs. My EJBs are declared in the following way:

```
public interface MyEjb...

@Local
public interface MyEjbLocal extends MyEjb...

@Remote
public interface MyEjbRemote extends MyEjb...

@Stateless
public class MyEjbBean implements MyEjbLocal, MyEjbRemote...
```

When application starts I can see in WebSphere Liberty log that this EJB gets the following JNDI names:

```
java:global/my-ear-app-name/my-ejb-module-name/MyEjbBean!my.package.name.MyEjbLocal,
java:global/my-ear-app-name/my-ejb-module-name/MyEjbBean!my.package.name.MyEjbRemote
```

I need to change these names. If I understand it correctly, it can be done in the `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file. I have an `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file in the `META-INF` directory of my EJB module `jar` file. This file contains the following configuration:

```
<session name="MyEjbBean" simple-binding-name="my/new/jndi/name"></session>
```

However, this configuration does not have any effect: when I start the ear application I still see the default JNDI bindings in the log.

I know that `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` is picked up correctly by WebSphere Liberty, because when I specify a wrong bean name in the `<session>` tag, I get a warning in WebSphere log.

How can I change EJB JNDI bindings in WebSphere Liberty?

Comment: These names are mandated by the Java EE specification. Why do you need to change them? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Steve The actual JNDI binding looks like the following: `java:global/my-ear-app-name-1.2.3/my-ejb-module-name-1.2.3/MyEjbBean!my.package.name.MyEjbLocal`. Both the application name and EJB module name include the current version. So the binding changes every time the version changes.

Comment: Try setting the `<application-name>...</application-name>` in the application.xml, and the `<module-name>...</module-name>` in the various module deployment descriptors (ejb-jar.xml and web.xml). Make sure these DDs have the Java EE 7 versions in them.

Comment: @Steve Thanks! I fixed the problem by defining `<applicationName>` and `<bundleFileName>` in `maven-ear-plugin` (which generates `application.xml`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the simple-binding-name is ignored in ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml files for WebSphere
 Liberty.

It is mentioned in below doc (search for "simple-binding"):
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_restrict.html

Comment: Thanks for the clue. How can I change the JNDI bindings then?